# jQuery InsertAtCaret sometimes copies strange characters into a textarea

Tags: jquery, encoding, asp-classic

I'm getting weird characters, like Ã¢â‚¬â„¢t, copied into my textarea when selecting and inserting text from another DIV.

Not sure where they are coming from. How do I solve it?

Someone suggested it might be encoding; I'm doing this in Classic ASP with the following header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your character encoding to utalise the utf-8 charset

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```